# xcode project on GitHub, remove signing and identity?

Tags: xcode, github, identity, signing

I have several iOS App I have already published on the AppStore.

I would like to publish the code of these Apps on public GitHub repository, so anyone can get the code and play with it.

My question is, should I remove from my Xcode projects, for each App, the Identity and Signing?

How should I proceed to continue the dev of these Apps, publish on GitHub public repository and to make sure my identities and signing data are not public?